# Better way to run WMI queries?

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

I do most of my scripting in VBScript and I often use WMI queries to get information from the system.  The WMI ExecQuery method always returns a WMI collection object that I have to access from a `For` loop -- even in cases where you could only ever possibly return one item.  Here is an example:

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set objColItems = objWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS",,48)

For Each objItem In objColItems
    strManufacturer = objItem.Manufacturer
Next

...
```

In this example, all I need is the brand of computer (i.e. Dell, HP, etc.).  There should only ever be one instance of the Win32_BIOS class.

What's even more annoying, though, is when the class has multiple instances (say, `Win32_Printers` for example), and I know exactly which one I am looking for.  Then I have to insert an `If` to check the name.  It's an annoying amount of code when you're just looking for one piece of information from several classes.

I thought I saw a code sample once upon a time where someone accessed a property directly from an instance of a WMI class with a single line of code, but of course I didn't write it down.

So is there a way to do that without having to query for it and run it through a loop?

---

**Update:**

OK, I guess I just didn't Google hard enough, but I found out that what I am looking for is the [SWbemServices.Get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.  This allows you to get properties of a specific instance of a class without querying for it.

In the example they provide on that page, I can get the status of a service with just two lines of code:

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").Get("Win32_Service.Name='Spooler'")
WScript.Echo objWMI.State
```

Neat.  Except it only works in cases where there are multiple instances of the class and you know which one you're after.  A good find, but how do I use it in the example I gave above, where there is only one instance?

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.root\cimv2").Get("Win32_BIOS.Manufacturer")
```

Gives me an error: `Invalid object path.`

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.root\cimv2").Get("Win32_BIOS")
```

That line works, but it's not bound to an instance so all I get are nulls.

How do I use this technique for single-instance classes?  Like is there a way to specify the "default" instance?

Comment: `x = objColItems(0).Manufacturer`. Perhaps wmic easier, I use that. In a Command Prompt, `wmic bios get manufacturer`

Answer (score 0):

On Vista and later, you can use the `ItemIndex()` property:

```
strManufacturer = objColItems.ItemIndex(0).Manufacturer
```

Comment: Close to what I asked for, but I kinda reworded the question a little to be more specific about what I want. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.root\cimv2").Get("Win32_BIOS=@")
WScript.Echo objWMI.Manufacturer
```